# Find Source File Function Declaration Location from ELF

Tags: gcc, elf, decompiler

Given an ELF file, I run `readelf -sV bin/my_app | grep \ glob` on it. This returns:

```
   205: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND glob@GLIBC_2.27 (6)
   326: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND glob@GLIBC_2.17 (2)
   334: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND globfree@GLIBC_2.17 (2)
 21011: 0000000000cd2748     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   26 global_mask
 21968: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS globals_io.o
 40039: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND glob@@GLIBC_2.27
 46623: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND glob@GLIBC_2.17
 47377: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND globfree@@GLIBC_2.17
```

With the information in this output, can I find the location in my source files where this glob symbol is invoked? I would like to find the location to understand why two different versions of GLIBC are linked for the same symbol.

Answer (score 1):

> With the information in this output, can I find the location in my source files where this glob symbol is invoked?

No.

You could do: `objdump -d bin/my_app`, find `CALL`s to the two versions of `glob`, and *that* will tell you what functions the calls are coming from.

> I would like to find the location to understand why two different versions of GLIBC are linked for the same symbol.

It's not "two different versions of GLIBC", it's "two different `glob` symbols with different ABIs".

I didn't think it was possible to reference different versions of `glob` in the same ELF binary, unless you do some creative symbol aliasing with `asm(".symver ...")` directives. Once you know which function references the (old) `glob@GLIBC_2.17` symbol, run preprocessor on the file in which that function is defined, and I'd be very surprised if there is no `asm(".symversion...")` in that file.